# SQL Server - Insert into table from a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I am curious on the insert command behaves.

I have an issue on inserting row into a table from a view. Both of the table and view have the same schema.

I tried to insert all rows in a view into a table, but the numbers of inserted rows are not tally. I tried both of the following insert command.

****1st*****

```
SELECT 
INTO  tblTABLEABC 
FROM v_ViewABC
```

****2nd****

```
INSERT INTO tblTABLEABC 
SELECT * FROM v_ViewABC
```

The count in v_ViewABC supposedly have 1291 rows. But after executed the insert command, tblTABLEABC only have 731 rows. Same things happen on both insert commands. I tried in SQL Server.

I am not sure if is there any limitation or rules in SQL Server on this? Appreciate if anyone got an answer for this.

Thanks.

Comment: does your destination table have a matching schema to the view and are there any constraints on the columns you are inserting into?

Comment: Can you supply the view definition?

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the following code, and provide the results?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT1 FROM v_ViewABC

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT*) AS COUNT1 FROM v_ViewABC
```